# Calculate the Normal of a vertex in maya with Python

Tags: maya

I have a script when I make a light it points to my object. I did this with a normalConstrain. But is there any other way to do this without constrains ?

I think I need to calculate the normal of the closest vertex form my Light ? 
But I don't know how to do this, if someone can help me would be nice !

[See Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uOqwb.jpg)

Here is how I did the NormalConstrain :

```
    myNormalConstrain = cmds.normalConstraint('mySphere','myLight', aimVector = (0,0,1), worldUpType = 'scene',name='NormalConstrainToObject')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to create a closestPointOnMesh node an connect it to the `worldMesh` attribute of your mesh.  The only wrinkle is that there's a bug in Maya 2016 (not sure about others) where the normal value coming back from the node is not actually normalized if you are using units other than centimeters.  Here's a function which does it:

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
import maya.api.OpenMaya as api


def get_closest_normal(surface, x, y , z):
    node = cmds.createNode('closestPointOnMesh')
    cmds.connectAttr(surface + '.worldMesh ', node + ".inMesh")
    cmds.setAttr( node + ".inPosition", x, y, z, type='double3')
    normal = cmds.getAttr(node + ".normal")
    # there's a bug in Maya 2016 where the normal
    # is not properly normalized.  Not sure
    # if it's fixed in other years....  this
    # is the workaround

    result = api.MVector(*normal)
    cmds.delete(node)
    result.normalize()
    return result


print get_closest_normal('pSphereShape1', 10, 1, 1)
```

Instead of getting the number and deleting the node as done here, you could keep the node around and connect it's normal attribute to something for live updates.  This is a fairly expensive node to update, however, so don't use that version for something like an animation rig without testing performance to be sure it's affordable

Comment: Thank you sir ! But how can I get the rotation of this ? So my light is pointing to the vertex .

Comment: A normal is just a vector, you really need at least two to calculate a rotation.  You might want to look at [this question[(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50279667/getting-rotation-with-the-distancedimension-in-maya-with-python/50282957#50282957) for an example of how to use an aim constraint for something similar -- you'd feed the normal here into the aim constraint's up vector to align the light to the surface